# Top app bar not scrolling when custom size is set

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

Whenever I navigate within my screen the `LazyColumn` scrolls perfectly but the top app bar doesn't move at all. Is it possible to tell the enlarged top app bar to scroll or can this only be done with the 4 default top app bars provided in Material 3?

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior()

    val mConfiguration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val mScreenHeight = mConfiguration.screenHeightDp.dp
    val mSize = mScreenHeight / 2

    Column {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(mSize)
                .weight(1f)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            LargeTopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(
                        text = "Android Studio Dolphin", overflow = TextOverflow.Visible, maxLines = 1
                    )
                },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior)
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(mSize)
                .weight(1f)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Green)
        ) {
            MyScreenContent()
            //   contentPadding ->
            // MyScreenContent(contentPadding = contentPadding)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()
) {
    Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val listState = rememberLazyListState()

        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            contentPadding = contentPadding,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        ) {
            item {
                Text(text = "text", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 18.sp))
            }

            items(75) {
                ListItem(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Scaffold` applying the `nestedScroll` modifier.

Something like:

```
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
    topBar = {
        LargeTopAppBar(
            title = {
                Text(
                    text = "Android Studio Dolphin", overflow = TextOverflow.Visible, maxLines = 1
                )
            },
            scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior)
    },
    content = { innerPadding ->
        LazyColumn(contentPadding = innerPadding,){
            //....
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: What about the custom height?

Comment: @wbk727 You can apply the same `Modifier.nestedScroll` to the `LazyColumn` and the `TopAppBar` will scroll with the `LazyColumn` also in your code, but not the entire `Box`. Please note that the `TopAppBar` has a max height of `152.0.dp`